# ¿De qué forma puedo saber si un documento obtenido desde un campo del tipo «referencia» es nulo en Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estuve preguntando [en SO en inglés sin ningún éxito](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55514273/5587982), así que me lanzo por aquí a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

En mi método `launchFirestore()` intento obtener datos en dos instancias:

1. Obtengo una referencia `calRef`, la cual, según la fecha del día me busca un campo que es del tipo **referencia**, o sea, ese campo lo que hace es apuntar a otro documento (es lo más cercano que encuentro a las llaves foráneas de las bases de datos). Digamos que en el campo `1` de `calRef` tengo esa referencia a otro documento, obteniéndolo aquí: `DocumentReference dataRef=calSnapshot.getDocumentReference("1");`
2. Obtengo los datos que habría en `dataRef` en la otra parte del código `if (calSnapshot != null && calSnapshot.exists()) {
                       dataRef.get(). ...`

Eso funciona bien cuando la ruta que apunta a `dataRef` existe. Pero cuando no existe la App se detiene, lanzando un error NPE.

Aquí pensé que controlaba el estado de nulidad de `dataRef`, pero no lo hace:

```
                if (e != null || dataRef==null) {
                    launchVolley();
                    return;
                }
```

Lo que debería ocurrir según mi lógica es que cuando la ruta a que apunta `dataRef` no exista, se lanzaría `launchVolley()` para buscar los datos en el servidor. Pero no lo hace. Hice una prueba poniendo una ruta de documento que no existe e imprimiendo en el Log el snapshot. Me muestra esto:

> ```
>  D/OficioActivity: DocumentSnapshot{key=liturgia/lh/1/307040501,
>  metadata=SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=false},
>  doc=null}
> ```

Ahí se ve claramente que `doc=null`, supongo que será mi ruta `liturgia/lh/1/307040501` que no existe. Lo que no sé es cómo poder verificar si esa ruta no existe, para entonces lanzar Volley.

Este es el código completo de mi método.

```
 public void launchFirestore() {
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        String fechaDD = strFechaHoy.substring(6, 8);
        String fechaMM = strFechaHoy.substring(4, 6);
        String fechaYYYY = strFechaHoy.substring(0, 4);
        String calendarPath = "calendar";

        DocumentReference calRef = db.collection(calendarPath).document(fechaYYYY).collection(fechaMM).document(fechaDD);
        calRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot calSnapshot,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                DocumentReference dataRef=calSnapshot.getDocumentReference("1");
                if (e != null || dataRef==null) {
                    launchVolley();
                    return;
                }

                if (calSnapshot != null && calSnapshot.exists()) {
                    dataRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            mBreviario = dataSnapshot.toObject(Breviario.class);
                            Log.d(TAG,dataSnapshot.toString());
                            showData();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    launchVolley();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En esta línea hay un posible NPE:

```
DocumentReference dataRef=calSnapshot.getDocumentReference("1");
```

Hay un if con el que lo estas controlando pero esa instrucción queda fuera, debería estar así:

```
    public void launchFirestore() {
            final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            String fechaDD = strFechaHoy.substring(6, 8);
            String fechaMM = strFechaHoy.substring(4, 6);
            String fechaYYYY = strFechaHoy.substring(0, 4);
            String calendarPath = "calendar";

            DocumentReference calRef = db.collection(calendarPath).document(fechaYYYY).collection(fechaMM).document(fechaDD);
            calRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot calSnapshot,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (calSnapshot != null && calSnapshot.exists()) {
                        DocumentReference dataRef=calSnapshot.getDocumentReference("1");
                        if (e != null || dataRef==null) {
                            launchVolley();
                            return;
                        }
                        dataRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                mBreviario = dataSnapshot.toObject(Breviario.class);
                                Log.d(TAG,dataSnapshot.toString());
                                showData();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        launchVolley();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Esa es precisamente la línea del NPE y lo que pregunto es cómo controlarlo.

Comment: Edito la respuesta con el código completo. Estabas accediendo a calSnapshot sin haber comprobado primero que fuera distinto de nulo, ahora dentro del if que lo comprueba ya no deberías tener problema.

Comment: Esto da el mismo resultado. El problema no es `calSnapshot`, ese objeto no es nulo porque lo obtengo correctamente. Lo que no puedo llegar a controlar es que el campo de tipo `reference` que guardo en `calSnapshot` no sea nulo. Con tu código tengo igualmente un NPE. Y en el Log `calSnashot` muestra esto: `DocumentSnapshot{key=liturgia/lh/1/03070407, metadata=SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=false}, doc=null}` Aquí se ve el valor de mi campo de tipo `reference`, que es este: `liturgia/lh/1/03070407` yo puse ahí un documento que no existe a propósito, pero no logro saber...

Comment: ...algún modo de controlar que en esa referencia no hay nada. Yo veo esto en el Log: `doc=null` y me pregunto si no hay alguna forma de comprobar ese valor de `doc` ¿?

Comment: @A.Cedano existe un método `calSnapshot.contains("1")`, creo que te puede valer ;)

Comment: Gracias Ydrojen. Si te fijas el problema no es `calSnapshot` en sí, sino el campo de tipo referencia que guardo en `calSnapshot`, este `liturgia/lh/1/03070407`, al que intento acceder en una segunda instancia. Si hago `calSnapshot.contains("1")` no me dará `false` porque de hecho contiene un campo `1` como se puede ver aquí: `DocumentReference dataRef=calSnapshot.getDocumentReference("1");` el problema es la referencia de documento que existe en el campo `1`, que quiero controlar cuando sea nula.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, y perdón por las vueltas que estamos dando. Una pregunta, ¿sigue retornando un NPE? ¿Esta línea la ejecuta correctamente `dataRef.get().addOnSuccessListener`? ¿Llega a entrar en el onSuccess de ese listener?

Comment: Cuando la referencia que se busca ahí existe entra en el `dataRef.get().addOnSuccessListener`, pero si no existe no entra, dando un NPE y la app hace crash. Eso es lo que quiero evitar precisamente. Verás, yo estoy trabajando con Firebase y con Volley al mismo tiempo, si la referencia buscada no existe en Firebase, tendría que buscar esos datos en mi servidor, usando `Volley`, pero no encuentro forma de hacer eso cuando **ese campo de tipo referencia no existe**. El asunto es que mi app usa contenido que se repite cíclicamente cada cierto tiempo, por eso he creado un calendario con referencias

Comment: La verdad me quedo sin ideas. Según la documentación (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getDocumentReference(java.lang.String)) el método getDocumentReference solo lanza un RuntimeException, si te esta dando un NPE debería ser porque calSnapshot sea nulo pero ya lo has metido dentro del if que comprueba presisamente que no lo es... Solo se me ocurre que me pongal la traza completa del NPE a ver si viendo por qué clases pasa se me enciende la bombilla.