# Metodos asincronos Android Studio Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, asincronismo

Necesito hacer una consulta a base de datos firebase(Cloud Firestore) como muestro ahora:

```
 db.collection("Usuarios").get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
                            lista.add(d.getId().toString());
                        }
                        for (String r : lista) {
                            if (r.equals(usu)) {
                              usuExis=true;
                            } else {
                                usuExis=false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

y quiero que el proceso no avance hasta que la respuesta ASINCRONA no haya sido retornada.
¿Como se hace?
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo que *el proceso no avance hasta que la respuesta ASINCRONA no haya sido retornada*? ¿Qué quieres decir con eso? El código a partir de aquí: `List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();` se ejecutará cuando haya respuesta. Puedes llenar tu objeto ahí y luego pasarlo a otra parte si quieres o trabajarlo ahí mismo. ¿Cuál es entonces tu duda/problema/error?

Comment: Me refiero fuera de ese método, cuando quiero utilizar el valor que se da a usuExis, al ser un método asincrono, dicha variable no cambia hasta que la respuesta del método llegue.

Comment: Solamente tienes que llamar al método después de la asignación: `for (String r : lista) {
                            if (r.equals(usu)) {
                              usuExis=true;
                            } else {
                                usuExis=false;
                            }
                        }
llamaATuMetodoAqui();`

Comment: El metodo asincrono es el que pongo en la descripcion, y quiero que ese metodo al terminar retorne un valor para despues utilizarla. Pero como el metodo es asincrono la respuesta llega mas tarde y por tanto el valor de usuExis no cambia y siempre se mantiene el false.

Comment: A ver, lo más simple es que declares a `usuExis` como miembro de la clase y que llames al método desde dentro de la llamada a Firestore. Si quieres hacerlo al revés también puedes, pero en ese caso tienes que meter **toda la petición a Firebase dentro de un método** y retornar el valor desde ese método.  La petición es un todo, el método no es este solamente: `public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {` sino también lo que está antes, donde se crea la referencia a la colección.

Comment: Mira cómo se estructura el código [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/251930/29967) en el método **`launchFirestore()`**. Se hace la asignación desde dentro de la petición a Firebase a un miembro de la clase que es `mBreviario`, y una vez hecha se invoca a `showData()` para mostrar los datos. Y si hay error se invoca a otros métodos alternativos. Así el código queda mejor organizado y más claro que tener que retornar datos desde dentro de la petición de Firebase hacia fuera.

Answer (score 0):

En estos casos yo lo que suelo hacer es crear una interfaz con un método que reciba un argumento con el valor que necesito, en tu caso un booleano. Después, encapsulas tu lógica dentro de un método que reciba como argumento la interfaz.
Para que se entienda mejor voy a hacer un ejemplo con tu código:

1.- Crear la interfaz:

```
public interface UserInterface{void userExist(boolean user);}
```

2.- Encapsular tu lógica:

```
    public void logicaUserExist(final UserInterface valorInterface){
    db.collection("Usuarios").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
                    lista.add(d.getId().toString());
                }
                for (String r : lista) {
                    if (r.equals(usu)) {
                        usuExis=true;
                    } else {
                        usuExis=false;
                    }
                } 
                valorInterface.userExist(usuExis); //aquí ya almacenas el valor para luego poder utilizarlo
            }
        });
}
```

3.- Utilizar el valor obtenido:

```
logicaUserExist(new UserInterface(){
    @Override
    public void userExist(boolean user){
        //aquí pones la lógica que quieras con ese valor
    }
});
```